# Windows Tortoisehg can't show incoming preview

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

On windows tortoisehg, clicking "incoming" can't show the list of incoming changesets, only saying "incoming changesets found".

How to make the incoming changesets shown?

Comment: Is remote repo also Mercurial?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Branch` combo box that allows you to see only a specific branch. This combo box is at the top of your graph in TortoiseHg, if you enable the `Graph Filter` (CTRL-S).

In your case, it is quite probable that you already selected a specific branch. Having this combo box to anything else than `Show All`, will show you only the incoming changesets of the selected branch.

Comment: `CTRL-S` is **Filter Toobar**, not related to branch selection

Comment: @LazyBadger I didn't make the UI, that's where it is.

Comment: This is **only** for changesets-list view, **not related** with `hg incoming`'s GUI

Comment: @LazyBadger Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply. but the problem is Windows Tortoisehg doesn't recognize bundle() filter.

please see the screen shot:
[image: windows tortoisehg not showing incoming changesets.png]

Comment: OMFG!!!! bundle() revset **will never work** inside *repository*! READ `hg help revsets` "Changesets in the bundle. Bundle must be specified by the -R option."

Comment: @LazyBadger the linux tortoisehg works, the bundle() filter is just shown automatically when clicking the incoming button